# Android Chrome custom tabs fade in animation

Tags: android

I have an app with a Chrome custom tab. I can get enter and exit animations working with the builder as long as they are transitions (enter/exit from left/right):

```
.setStartAnimations(mContext, R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_left)
.setExitAnimations(mContext, R.anim.enter_from_left, R.anim.exit_to_right)
```

As soon as I try and have a fade in/out animation with alpha it doesn't work. I get a black screen and have to kill the app from multitasking. Animation XML fade in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/linear"
>
<alpha
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:duration="500"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    />
</set>
```

fade out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/linear"
>
<alpha
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:toAlpha="0.0"
    android:duration="500"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    />
</set>
```

I have tried changing the interpolator and fill after/before but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 4):

I am doing exactly this in my app and have no problem at all.

```
                   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                        CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
                        builder.setToolbarColor(ResourceUtils.getColor(R.color.mine_shaft));
                        builder.setStartAnimations(activity, R.anim.slide_up, R.anim.no_change);
                        builder.setExitAnimations(activity, R.anim.no_change, R.anim.slide_down);
                        CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
                        customTabsIntent.launchUrl(activity, Uri.parse(url));
                    } else {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                        activity.startActivity(intent);
                    }
```

And this is what my animation XML looks like,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromYDelta="100%p"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        android:toYDelta="0" />

    <alpha
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromAlpha="0.4"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />
</set>
```

Just to check your problem, I have tried removing the translation from this animation, keeping only the fading part and it still works perfectly.

Please give this a try. I am sure there is some minor mistake you are making somehwere.

Comment: I think its the fromAlpha="0.0" that is the problem in mine

Comment: Yes, it can be the problem. If this answer helps you, please consider upvoting it.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out if you don't use an animation set it works. So the XML becomes:

fade in:

```
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/decelerate_quad"
android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
android:duration="1000" />
```

fade out:

```
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_quad"
android:fromAlpha="1.0"
android:toAlpha="0.0"
android:duration="1000"
/>
```